# What is the equivalent of Git `--no-ff` in Mercurial?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

In Git I can do this to merge branches:

```
git merge --no-ff release-1.2
```

How can I do that in Mercurial?

Comment: I fixed your capitalization for you.

Answer (score 0):

http://hgtip.com/tips/advanced/2010-04-23-debug-command-tricks/, number 3 "Simulate Git’s --no-ff merges with anonymous heads".